# Magento Custom module for Mobile API taking too much time to send response

Tags: api, magento, curl, loading, magento-1.9

I have created custom module for Mobile API with below code:

AppController.php

```
<?php

class <NameSpace>_<Module>_AppController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function loginAction() {
        $postData = json_decode($_POST['login_details'], true);
        if (($postData['email'] != '') && ($postData['password'] != '')) {
            $email = $postData['email'];
            $password = $postData['password'];
            Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
            $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
            $customer->website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
            $customer->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());
            try {
                $customer->loadByEmail($email);
                $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $session->login($email, $password);
                $response['success'] = '1';
                $response['message'] = 'Login Successfull.';
                $response['status_code'] = '200';
                $response['data'] = $customer->getData();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $response['success'] = '0';
                $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
                $response['status_code'] = $e->getCode();
            }
        } else {
            $response['success'] = '0';
            $response['message'] = 'Login Fail : Please Enter Email Id and Password.';
            $response['status_code'] = '400';
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[NameSpace]_[Module]>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </[NameSpace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <[module]>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>[NameSpace]_[Module]</module>
                    <frontName>mobileapi</frontName>
                </args>
            </[module]>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

When I call login API via Curl its taking too much time to show response:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://[website-url]/mobileapi/app/login",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'email' => 'test@mail.com',
        'password' => '123456',
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<br/>CLOSE";
exit();
```

CURL executed successfully but every time its taking too much time for execution.
Can any one guide me to reduce the execution time of API in custom module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me to get faster API response:

```
public function loginAction() {
            $postData = json_decode($_POST['login_details'], true);
            $flag = 0;
            $cacheId = 'login_' . $postData['email'].$postData['password'];

            if (false !== ($data = Mage::app()->getCache()->load($cacheId))) {
                $data = unserialize($data);
                if($data['success']==1){
                    $flag = 1;
                    $response=$data['response'];
                }
            }
            if ($flag == 0) {

                if (($postData['email'] != '') && ($postData['password'] != '')) {
                    $email = $postData['email'];
                    $password = $postData['password'];
                    Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
                    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
                    $customer->website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
                    $customer->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());
                    try {
                        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
                        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                        $session->login($email, $password);
                        $response['success'] = '1';
                        $response['message'] = 'Login Successfull.';
                        $response['status_code'] = '200';
                        $response['data'] = $customer->getData();
                        $data['success'] = 1;
                        $data['response']=$response;
                        Mage::app()->getCache()->save(serialize($data), $cacheId);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $response['success'] = '0';
                        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
                        $response['status_code'] = $e->getCode();
                    }
                } else {
                    $response['success'] = '0';
                    $response['message'] = 'Login Fail : Please Enter Email Id and Password.';
                    $response['status_code'] = '400';
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
            exit;
}
```